# Error reading characters of a string and Access Violation

Tags: c++, visual-studio, class, vector

So I am trying to make this program work for an assignment in school. Right now there are multiple instances where it says  and if I just try to run it it says

Unhandled exception at 0x000D3619 in Project5.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x00000000.

What is happening here? I know it has something to do with the way I'm opening the file and  my vector. But I don't know what.

Here is my main function:

```
int main()
{
    vector<shape*> shapes;
    shapes.resize(1000);

    ifstream fs;
    string filen = "shapers.txt";
    fs.open(filen.c_str());
    string obj="";
    fs>>obj;
    //int j=0;
    while (!fs.fail()) {
      if (obj == "Sphere") {
        double radius;
        fs>>radius;
        shapes.push_back(new sphere(radius));
        //shapes[j] = new sphere(radius);
      } else if (obj == "Cuboid") {
        double width, height, length;
        fs >> width >> length >> height;
        shapes.push_back(new cuboid(width,length,height));
        //shapes[j] = new cuboid(width,length,height);
      } else if (obj == "Cylinder") {
        double radius, height;
        fs >> radius >> height;
        shapes.push_back(new cylinder(radius,height));
        //shapes[j] = new cylinder(radius,height);
      }
      fs >> obj;
      //j++;
    }
    fs.close();


    for (int i=0; i<=5; i++)
    {
        shapes[i]->display();
        cout<<endl;
    }
    maxSurfaceArea(shapes);

    expandAll(2);

    for (int i=0; i<=5; i++)
    {
        shapes[i]->display();
        cout<<endl;
    }
    //cout<<shapes[0]<<" "<<shapes[1]<<" "<<shapes[2]<<" "<<shapes[3]<<" "<<shapes[4]<<" "<<shapes[5]<<endl;



    pause_215(true);
    return 0;

}
```

Comment: Add logging or use a debugger.

Answer (score 2):

The first thing you do is:

```
shapes.resize(1000);
```

Then as you read in shapes, you call

```
shapes.push_back(...
```

So your vector will be of size 1001, 1002, ... etc. The first 1000 shape pointers are going to give you the access violations as you've seen.

You should either just call

```
shapes.reserve(1000)
```

in the beginning, or frankly just leave that line out entirely since you're only expecting <10 shapes (order of magnitude)

Comment: Resizing a vector of pointers is cheap, so probably removing that line is best.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz Agreed. If they were indeed expecting 1000 or 10000 pointers, then perhaps a `reserve` is warranted. But for 5 (in their case) might as well just let it size itself.

Comment: I changed it to simply 'vector<shape*> shapes;'. And now it gives me an abort message because it said the vector subscript was out of range.

Comment: Get rid of the <= 5. Use < shapes.size() to make sure you do not access a subscript that does not exist.